# Como mostrar o resultado de uma consulta baseado no resultado de outra?

Tags: sql, query

*Consulta A:*

```
   SELECT V.CHAPA AS CHAPA,
       F.NOME AS NOME,
       V.DATA AS DATA,
       DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(BATIDA), MAX(BATIDA)) AS DIFF
FROM V_BATIDASANTIGAS AS V
LEFT JOIN V_DADOSFUNC AS F ON V.CHAPA = F.CHAPA
WHERE V.BATIDA IS NOT NULL
  AND SEQUENCIALBATIDA IN (2,
                           3)
  AND MONTH (V.DATA) = 9
GROUP BY V.CHAPA,
         V.DATA,
         F.NOME
HAVING DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(BATIDA), MAX(BATIDA)) < 60
AND DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(BATIDA), MAX(BATIDA)) > 0
ORDER BY DATA DESC
```

*Consulta B:*

```
SELECT V.CHAPA AS CHAPA,
       F.NOME AS NOME,
       V.DATA AS DATA,
       V.CODCOLIGADA
FROM V_BATIDASANTIGAS AS V
LEFT JOIN V_DADOSFUNC AS F ON V.CHAPA = F.CHAPA
WHERE V.BATIDA IS NOT NULL
  AND V.CODCOLIGADA = 1
GROUP BY V.CHAPA,
         V.DATA,
         F.NOME,
         V.CODCOLIGADA
HAVING (MAX(V.SEQUENCIALBATIDA) > 4
        OR MAX(V.SEQUENCIALBATIDA) = 1)
ORDER BY DATA DESC
```

Preciso exibir o resultado da *Consulta A* desconsiderando os registros da *Consulta B*.

Um exemplos seria algo como:

```
IF (Relsultado_Consulta_A == Relsultado_Consulta_B) 
BEGIN DECARTAR RESULTADOS IGUAIS 
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN MOSTRA RESULTADOS QUE EXISTEM APENAS NA CONSULTA A 
END
```

Como poderia fazer ?

Comment: Pelo que entendi você quer os valores em `A` que não estejam em `B`, certo? Existe alguma coluna em especial, ou são todas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar um `SELECT DISTINCT` com o `UNION` entre as duas consultas

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM
(
  SELECT * FROM CONSULTA_A
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM CONSULTA_B
) CONSULTAS
```

O `UNION` vai juntar os resultados das duas tabelas. E o `DISTINCT` vai trazer apenas os resultados não repetidos.

---

**EDIT**

Depois do que conversamos nos comentários, talvez isso resolva:

```
SELECT A.CHAPA,
    A.NOME,
    A.DATA,
    A.DIFF,
    B.CODCOLIGADA

FROM
(
    SELECT V.CHAPA AS CHAPA,
           F.NOME AS NOME,
           V.DATA AS DATA,
           DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(BATIDA), MAX(BATIDA)) AS DIFF
    FROM V_BATIDASANTIGAS AS V
    LEFT JOIN V_DADOSFUNC AS F ON V.CHAPA = F.CHAPA
    WHERE V.BATIDA IS NOT NULL
      AND SEQUENCIALBATIDA IN (2,
                               3)
      AND MONTH (V.DATA) = 9
    GROUP BY V.CHAPA,
             V.DATA,
             F.NOME
    HAVING DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(BATIDA), MAX(BATIDA)) < 60
    AND DATEDIFF(mi, MIN(BATIDA), MAX(BATIDA)) > 0
) A
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT V.CHAPA AS CHAPA,
           F.NOME AS NOME,
           V.DATA AS DATA,
           V.CODCOLIGADA
    FROM V_BATIDASANTIGAS AS V
    LEFT JOIN V_DADOSFUNC AS F ON V.CHAPA = F.CHAPA
    WHERE V.BATIDA IS NOT NULL
      AND V.CODCOLIGADA = 1
    GROUP BY V.CHAPA,
             V.DATA,
             F.NOME,
             V.CODCOLIGADA
    HAVING (MAX(V.SEQUENCIALBATIDA) > 4
            OR MAX(V.SEQUENCIALBATIDA) = 1)
) B
ON A.CHAPA = B.CHAPA
AND A.NOME = B.NOME
AND A.DATA = B.DATA
ORDER BY A.DATA DESC
```

Comment: Usei, mais somou os dois, mais não desconsiderou a consulta b

Comment: Então existem valores que são diferentes entre a consulta A e a consulta B. Você verificou se são *todos* os valores iguais?

Comment: Nas duas consultas os únicos campos iguais são:  V.CHAPA AS CHAPA,
    F.NOME  AS NOME, V.DATA  AS DATA, o ultimo campo de cada consulta é diferente,por isso vai sempre somar mesmo,teria alguma outra forma de fazer sem ser com o DISTINCT  ?

Comment: Tem sim, vou montar outra resposta. Um minuto. Talvez a resposta do @Willian já resolva!

Comment: Fiz um outro exemplo. Pode testar?

Comment: Testado e validado, Obrigado !

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o `Union all`, porem na segunda consulta utilizar o `not exists` comparando os dois resultados.

```
SELECT A.CHAPA
      ,A.NOME
      ,A.DATA
      ,A.DIFF
      ,CODE = NULL
FROM #TMP_A A   -- seria a consulta A
UNION ALL
SELECT B.CHAPA
      ,B.NOME
      ,B.DATA
      ,DIFF = NULL
      ,B.CODE
FROM (SELECT CHAPA = B.CHAPA
            ,NOME = B.NOME
            ,DATA = B.DATA
            ,CODE = B.CODE
     FROM #TMP_B B  -- Seria a consulta b
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM #TMP_A bA
                       WHERE bA.CHAPA = B.CHAPA)
) B
GO
```

O primeiro `select` irá retornar todos os registros de `#TMP_A`, e no segundo `select` você retorna de `#TMP_B` todos os itens que não existem em `#TMP_A`.